# Java - How to draw dashed and wavy lines?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, draw, java-2d

I want to draw dashed and wavy lines in java.
I can draw normal lines using `Graphics` - and the `g.drawLine()` method.
Is there an easy way to draw dashed and wavy lines in `Graphics2D` or something like that?

Right now I draw the lines using the coordinates of the `MouseListener`. So its something like MS Paint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing dashed line in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989082/drawing-dashed-line-in-java)

Comment: Are the lines all horizontal/vertical or can they be at any angle?

Comment: @AndrewThompson they can be any angle. The dashed line problem is solved. I'm having problems with the wavy line now.

Comment: Tip: Be sure to add @DavidPostill (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* a person of a new comment.  Exactly one person can be notified per comment.

Comment: At the moment it seems to be down, but hopefully this is only temporary: The site http://www.jhlabs.com/java/java2d/strokes/ contains some nice example of complex strokes. They show some nice stoke tricks that go beyond dashed lines (where the latter are actually covered by the basic tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html ...)

Answer (score 1):

Dashed lines, [as presented by Kevin Workman:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989406/3536342)

```
 public void drawDashedLine(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){

            //creates a copy of the Graphics instance
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{9}, 0);
            g2d.setStroke(dashed);
            g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

            //gets rid of the copy
            g2d.dispose();
    }
```

You can create dashed lines like using this.

Wavy Lines, [as presented by Tiger:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13114614/3536342)

```
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CurveDraw extends JFrame {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                CurveDraw frame = new CurveDraw();
                frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        public CurveDraw() {
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setSize(400,400);
        }
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
                QuadCurve2D.Double curve = new QuadCurve2D.Double(50,100,100,170,150,100);
                ((Graphics2D)g).draw(curve);
        }
}
```

[Docs.oracle to learn more about Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)
 **[wavy line](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/169781/Draw-wavy-line-sinewave-on-inkcanvas)**

**[Curvy line](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104820/Drawing-Trig-Functions-via-WPF)**

**[Docs.oracle to learn more about Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)**

Comment: Thanks i will try that.. but what about wavy lines?

Comment: updated @Mike_NotGuilty. these were saved on my computer. they should work.

Comment: Please don't recommend that folks, especially newbies like @Mike_NotGuilty, draw directly in a JFrame's paint method. Seeing this is like nails scratching a chalkboard. It makes me sick to my stomach.

Comment: Point taken. thumbs up @HovercraftFullOfEels.

Comment: i'm drawing inside a seperate JPanel. I tried your code but the wavy line is just like an arc. but it should be a wave like `sin(x)`

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) - When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all of the following:

    Provide a link to the original page or answer
    Quote only the relevant portion
    Provide the name of the original author

Comment: you can figure it out how to use arc as a wavy line?

Comment: @DavidPostill point taken but i dont know who was the author. i save many things that i find useful and these were one of them. From now i will make sure that i save author's name or links .. thanks.

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi - Your first answer is from http://stackoverflow.com/a/21989406/3536342, your second is from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13114614/3536342. By the way the second answer is not a good one. See comments in the second link.